# How can I change symfony2 form fields default options globally?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

Is there a way to change default options for form fields globally in symfony2?

More specifically, I want to change the render of **ALL** datetime fields to use `single_text` instead of the default `choice` widget.

Can it be done? Or do I need to implement a custom type and set the default in there, like for example the `birthdate` type?

I prefer an option that leads to minimal changes in the codebase.

Answer (score 2):

The post is old, but you can use an alternative method, overriding the DateType symfony class ...

service.yml

```
services:

    form.type.date:
        class: "YourApp\YourBundle\Form\DateType"
        tags:
            - { name: "form.type", alias: "date" }
```

DateType.php

```
<?php

namespace  YourApp\YourBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType as SymfonyDateType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class  DateType  extends  SymfonyDateType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    { 
        parent::configureOptions( $resolver );
        $resolver->setDefault( 'widget', 'single_text' );
    } 
}
```

You can check if the service is taken by container

```
$ ./app/console debug:container | grep form.type.date
 form.type.date       YourApp\YourBundle\Form\DateType                                                       
 form.type.datetime   Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType
```

Comment: Useful, thanks. BTW, the generic way to do this : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10505#issuecomment-125153752

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a [form theme](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes).

It's very easy and requires only a little bit coding time. First of all, you have to know which block to customize; in that case, you can do something like

```
{% block my_data_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if type is defined and type == 'date' %}
        // do all your customization
    {% else %}
        // don't know ...
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_widget_simple %}
```

Now that you have defined this snippet of code, you can use it into your main template (or whatever you use into your form views) in that way

```
{% form_theme form 'YourBundle:Form:myDataWidget' %}
```

Last but not least important, you have to place your form theme into `Resources/views` folder. In my example, your path will be `Resources/views/Form/myDataWidget`

### Update

Did you tried with

```
{% set type = type|default('single_text') %}
```

or something like that?

Comment: Could you please add an especific example of how to made the datetime field as single text? I've tried setting the widget in the template but is not working. `{% set widget = 'single_text' %}`